# Chrome: Bug with SVG polygon animation?

Tags: google-chrome, animation, svg, polygon

I created recently a hangman SVG graphic with animations, you can find it here:

http://ykg-clan.de/svg/test/hangman_old.svg

This works perfectly in Firefox - but in Chrome, the polygons and polylines do not get animated correctly.

I've done this by setting the points on invisible first and then animating them to the desired position. Firefox seems to recognize that I wish that `x x,y y,z z` must become to `a a,b b,c c` because of the order of the coordinates. However, chrome does not get it.

How can I realize the animated polygon just as I did here but also working in chrome?

Thank you for help!

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21371

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acceptable Answer by [Erik Dahlström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109374/erik-dahlstrom):

[Bug Report on bugs.webkit.org](http://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21371)

Is actually really a bug ;).