# Chrome SVG animate tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, svg-animate

Someone can tell me why this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="800">

    <defs id="defs">
            <animate xlink:href="#poly_t1" attributeName="points" attributeType="XML" from="100,500 150,500 170,480 120,480" to="100,400 150,400 170,380 120,380" begin="0s" dur="3s" fill="freeze" ></animate>
            <animate xlink:href="#poly_t2" attributeName="points" attributeType="XML" from="100,500 150,500 150,500 100,500" to="100,500 150,500 150,400 100,400" begin="0s" dur="3s" fill="freeze" ></animate>
            <animate xlink:href="#poly_t3" attributeName="points" attributeType="XML" from="150,500 170,480 170,480 150,500" to="150,500 170,480 170,380 150,400" begin="0s" dur="3s" fill="freeze" ></animate>

    </defs>
    <g id="histo">
            <polygon id="poly_t1" points="100,500 150,500 170,480 120,480" fill="#cc0022" stroke="black"></polygon>
            <polygon id="poly_t2" points="100,500 150,500 150,500 100,500" fill="#cc0022" stroke="black" ></polygon>
            <polygon id="poly_t3" points="150,500 170,480 170,480 150,500" fill="#cc0022" stroke="black"></polygon>
    </g>

</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j2spu/2/

works on FF,Chrome 18 to 19,Safari,rekonq and more I think but not on Chrome 20 to 24 ?

Comment: Same bug as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916796/chrome-bug-with-svg-polygon-animation. http://bugs.webkit.org is the right place to go with this.

Comment: Seems to be https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21371