# SVG animation doesn't work in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, animation, svg

This animation works perfectly in Firefox... But not in Chrome. Polygons don't animate?
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WscqA/4/)

```
<polygon fill="url(#grad1)" points="503,275 529,275 529,275 503,275">
    <animate attributeName="points"
         calcMode="linear"
         begin="1s" dur="0.4s"
         from="503,275 529,275 529,275 503,275"
         to="503,275 529,275 843,335 789,335"
         fill="freeze"/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916796/chrome-bug-with-svg-polygon-animation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530894/chrome-svg-animate-tag.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome (upto Version 25.0.1364.152) does not support svg fully.

Some svg feature are not supported  in `Firefox` too. For example `animateTransform` tag which is the direct child of a svg tag does not animate the svg in `Firefox` and `chrome`, Though W3 document says it should animate the svg,

So it will be better to test your svg in `opera`,

Comment: animateTransform tag which is the direct child of a svg tag should animate in Firefox. If you have a non-working testcase, raise a bug in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: OK, so animateTransform animating an svg element is not part of SVG 1.1 (the current standard). It is proposed that it be added to SVG 2 but that's still a work in progress currently.

Comment: @RobertLongson,  I am sorry! but I didn't found any written doc that animateTransform animating an svg element is not part of SVG 1.1 in http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SVGElement . Any number of the following elements, in any order : and animateTransform is there in the element list,  I tested in Opera, there this animation is supported. What does it mean? Opera implemented svg wrongly ? Plz reply...

Comment: The ‘animateTransform’ element animates a transform attribute on a target element. <svg> elements don't have a transform attribute. What it means is that Opera is beginning to implement parts of SVG 2 even though the specification is not yet finished.

Comment: I asked for solution not reason why it doesn't work :)
But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me try again - didn't catch that you were only looking at Polygon. It looks like animate doesn't work directly on a polygon in Chrome, but you can get the same effect by putting a filter on the shape and animating the filter region. It's sort of hacky, but it gets you where you want:

```
   <filter id="animateClip" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="0%">
         <animate attributeName="height"
         attributeType="XML"
         calcMode="linear"
         dur="1s"
         from="0%"
         to="100%"
         fill="freeze"/>
        <feColorMatrix type="identity"/>
    </filter>
```

The colormatrix is there just to give a filter result. Chrome doesn't like empty filters.